# остановить или обнулить setInterval, нажатием на кнопку

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
function startTimer() {
  var TMR = setInterval(function() {
    function f(x) {
      return (x / 100).toFixed(2).substr(2)
    }

    var o = document.getElementById('timer'),
      w = 60,
      y = o.innerHTML.split(':'),
      v = y[0] * w + (y[1] - 1),
      s = v % w,
      m = (v - s) / w;
    if (s >= 0) {
       o.innerHTML = [f(m), f(s)].join(':');
    }else {
      clearInterval(TMR);
      location.reload();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем через **start**

Останавливаем через **pause**

Обнуляем через **stop**

```js
let [timer,interval,value,start,input,stop] = [null,1000,0,
            document.getElementById("start"),
            document.getElementById("input"),
            document.getElementById("stop")];
start.onclick = _ => {
    if (timer !== null) return;
    timer = setInterval(() => {
    value = value+1;
     input.value = value;
  }, interval); 
}
pause.onclick = _ => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
stop.onclick = _ => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
  input.value = 0;
  value = 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input id="stop" type="button" value="stop"/>
<input id="start" type="button" value="start"/>
<input id="pause" type="button" value="pause"/>
```